# mysql insert code produced following error: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

Below is my code for loading data in a mysql table (7 column of information):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import mysql.connector, csv, sys

csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='testuser', password= 'testuser', database='database')

cursor = cnx.cursor()

table=csv.reader(file("logs.txt"), delimiter='\t')

for row in table:

      cursor.execute("INSERT INTO first_table (column1, column2, column3, column4 , column5, column6, column7) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", row)

cnx.commit()

cnx.close()
```

Below is truncated content of what logs.txt file consist of, 7 columns (tab-delimited) and the last column (*mouse_phene_id*) may be empty or has single or multiple items delimited by space:

```
human_gene_symbol       entrez_id       homolog_id      hgnc_assoc      mouse_gene_symbol       mouse_mgi_id    mouse_phene_id
A1BG      1     11167   yes     A1bg      MGI:2152878           
A1CF      29974 16363   yes     A1cf      MGI:1917115     MP:0005387 MP:0005386 MP:0005388 MP:0005385 MP:0002873 MP:0010768 MP:0005369 MP:0005376 MP:0005384 MP:0005378 
A2M       2     37248   yes     A2m       MGI:2449119           
A3GALT2   127550        16326   yes     A3galt2   MGI:2685279           
A4GALT    53947 9690    yes     A4galt    MGI:3512453     MP:0005386 MP:0010768 MP:0005376      
A4GNT     51146 87446   yes     A4gnt     MGI:2143261     MP:0005384 MP:0002006 MP:0005385 MP:0005381 MP:0005387        
AAAS      8086  9232    yes     Aaas      MGI:2443767     MP:0005389 MP:0005386 MP:0005378      
AACS      65985 11322   yes     Aacs      MGI:1926144           
AADAC     13    37436   yes     Aadac     MGI:1915008
```

[image: logs.txt file screenshot]

I get the following error and since this is a common error, I tried everything that was posted on stackoverflow related to this error and still unfixed and stuck:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "insert_mysql.py", line 23, in <module>
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO first_table (column1, column2, column3, column4 , column5, column6, column7) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", row)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 551, in execute "Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement")
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

first_table:

[image: first_table_shot]

Greatly appreciate any help, advice. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show us several lines from the `logs.txt` file?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I edited my post which includes several lines of the logs.txt file. Please let me know if any other information is needed.

Comment: You seem to have multiple values inside columns? Where do the long value such as row 2 delineate between fields? Since tabs are difficult to render in SO, can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @Parfait Are you talking about adding a screenshot of the logs.txt file, if so I uploaded it right below the truncated content. So yes you're right, column 7 (mouse_phene_id) can either have no value, single or multiple values. If it  does have multiple values then they are delimited by space, but the overall logs.txt file which has 7 columns are delimited by tabs.

Comment: Current code renders: `NameError: name 'file' is not defined`

Comment: @Parfait Thank you for the feedback. Do you think the error your getting at your end stems from a version issue with Python. I'm using Python 2.7 and still getting the same error about the 'not all parameters..'

Comment: `file()` is a Python 2 method and replaced with `open()` in Python 3. Regardless, you should be using context manager, `with open(...)` as shown in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Comment: In your database, what data type is *mouse_mgi_id*?

Comment: @Partfait I added a screenshot of the table datatypes. I used longtext to specify the mouse_mgi_id column datatype.

Comment: Also, thank you for showing me the docs, I  tried the with open(...) in my code and replacing newline= ' ' with 'b' flag for python 2:https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer yet still encountering  the same 'not all parameters..' error. Unsure on how to proceed, any guidance or suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: Are you _certain_ that each line has exactly 7 tabs?  I am seeing way more whitepace than this.  Whether it is all tabs is another story.

Comment: So I triple checked my data and filled in the empty values with a value and it turns out there were actually 8 columns as opposed to 7 columns and two whitespaces in front of the last three columns. I reran the code, removing unnecessary material such as the extra column and whitespaces, and it finally worked. Sorry for not taking a closer look this is bioinformatics data; intrinsically messy and insane, should've known. Thank you everyone for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are seeing is likely being caused by a row in the `logs.txt` file which does not have the same number of items (7) which your insert prepared statement is expecting.  The error

> Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

means that you had one or more positional parameters which could not be assigned values, and hence were not used.

I can make two suggestions about where in the file the problem might be.  First, you log file may have one or more header lines, which might not have the same number of columns or types of values the script expects.  You may skip any number of initial lines via this:

```
skip_first_line = next(table)
skip_second_line = next(table)
# etc.
```

In other words, just call `next()` to consume any number of initial lines in the log file which do not contain the actual data you want to insert.

If not, then perhaps the problematic line is somewhere in the middle of the file.  You can try printing each row in your script, to see where it dies:

```
for row in table:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO first_table (column1, column2, column3, column4 , column5, column6, column7) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", row)
    print row
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback. I did exactly as you suggested, included the next() call and print, tested independently and together, still produced the same 'not all parameters were used..' error. Very stuck.